# Convert hour:min:sec column of type character to time

Tags: r, datetime, grouping, lubridate

I've a time column that's of type character. I want to convert it to some sort of time type. I like to use the `lubridate` package but I don't like the notation of the output. My goal is to later group the date per hour and count the cases. `df %>% group_by(floor_date(Tijd, "hour"))`.

Dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Tijd = c("01:00:00", "01:27:00", "09:25:00", "14:39:00", 
"15:35:00")), .Names = "Tijd", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The following code produces a a type where the `floor_date()` function doesn't work on.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Tijd = hms(Tijd))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  Tijd        
  <S4: Period>
1 1H 0M 0S    
2 1H 27M 0S   
3 9H 25M 0S   
4 14H 39M 0S  
5 15H 35M 0S
```

The following code gives an error:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Tijd = hms(Tijd)) %>%
  group_by(floor_date(Tijd, "hour"))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'origin' must be supplied.
```

Comment: `hms` returns a period class. `floor_date` needs a date-time object. That is the problem. You could turn hms into a date-time object with `as_date` but then everything will be set to a date of "1970-01-01". You might be better of to extract the hours with mutate and then use a group by statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way -

```
hr <- strptime(df$Tijd, format = '%H:%M:%S', 'GMT')
df$hr <- hour(hr)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in `chron` approach then

```
library(dplyr)
library(chron)

df %>% 
  mutate(Tijd = hours(times(Tijd)))
```

gives

```
   Tijd
  <dbl>
1  1.00
2  1.00
3  9.00
4 14.0 
5 15.0
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Tijd = c("01:00:00", "01:27:00", "09:25:00", "14:39:00", 
"15:35:00")), .Names = "Tijd", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```